# Competing risks with left-truncation and right-censoring

Tags: r, survival, censoring, competing-risks

Reading a paper "Cause-Specific Cumulative Incidence Estimation and the Fine and
Gray Model Under Both Left Truncation and Right Censoring" Geskus (2011).

I'm trying to implement the method and was wondering if anyone had any experience with it.

I was wondering how the weight values in Table 1 were calculated? I can't seem to figure it out.

As far as I can tell, once I have these weights then calculating the cumulative incidence functions is straightforward in R.

**EDIT**

I understand that there is a function in R called [finegray](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/survival/html/finegray.html). However, in its current form it cannot handle left-truncation?

**EDIT2**

I have discovered the R function *crprep* in package [mstate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mstate/mstate.pdf). This calculates the weights in the presence of right-censoring and left-truncation.

However, I'm still having trouble recreating Table 1 from Geskus (2011). I don't seem to get all the weights for id=3 that appear in Table 1. Any help would be greatly appreciated.